# if statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

The word `"true"` is in the database where its getting the data from, but the if statement is going to the else.

```
while(odbc_fetch_row($user)){
    echo "<div style='position:absolute;overflow:scroll;height:370px;'>";
    $name         = odbc_result($user, 'username');
    $email        = odbc_result($user, 'email');
    $admin        = odbc_result($user, 'admin');
    $lastLogin    = odbc_result($user, 'lastLogin');
    $userDisabled = odbc_result($user, 'disabled');
    $fullname     = odbc_result($user, 'firstName') . " " . odbc_result($user, 'lastName');

    echo "<br><h2> " . $name . "</h2>";
    echo $fullname . "<br>";
    echo " " . $email;
    echo "<br>Last Login Time: <br>" . $lastLogin;
    echo "<br>";

    if($userDisabled == "true"){
        echo "<input type='checkbox' class='disableUser' checked id='disableUser'>Disable User<br>";
    }else{
        echo "<input type='checkbox' class='disableUser' id='disableUser' >Disable User<br>";
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: `var_Dump($userDisabled)`

Comment: do a `var_dump($userDisabled)`, then. something like "true[space]" would throw off the comparison.

Comment: we are waiting for your dump .... :)

Comment: I think it's `bool(true)`

Comment: Why do you use strings for boolean values? just use boolean type. (tinyint(1)).

Answer (score 0):

so try with this :

```
if((is_bool($userDisabled) && $userDisabled === TRUE) || (is_string($userDisabled) && strtoupper($userDisabled) == "TRUE" ) {
# do your job
}else {
# you can eat or sleep :)
}
```

Comment: ya I can do that but any idea why my code doesn't work?

Comment: because you are trying to compare a string with a boolean, and that is not correct

Comment: no my code compares `$userDisabled` which is getting a string from the database, to `"true"` which is also a string, someone above commented that maybe there's a white space character getting stored at the end of my string or something